# LAMP Server Refused to Connect Error

Tags: apache2, lamp, webserver

All of a sudden, my LAMP server enabled sites won't load and my browser only displays "Connection Refused" after I did an update, upgrade, and dist-upgrade then restarted my system. How do I fix this? I can't seem to find any fix anywhere.

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but have you made sure your server is running?

Comment: Yup. The server is running. That I made sure of first before trying any solutions first. No errors were in the error log in /var/log/apache2.log. My friend says it's because of the latest update but can't really pin point the culprit.

Comment: You might want to add your current Ubuntu version, and the version you upgraded from to your post.

Comment: Can you include the output of `sudo iptables -S` in your question?